# How to return multiple rows or table for SqLite in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

I am using SqLite library for swift. I can return one row with this method,

```
  func getById(id:Int64) -> Row?{
        do{
            let query=Users.filter(Id==id)
            print(query.asSQL())
            var data = try db!.pluck(query)
            return data
        }catch{
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

This function is returning "`Row`" it's ok. But i am using tableView object so i need one dataSource.

How can i return table and set datasource for tableView, i have not found an example of this.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

I don't know all of your classes, but this is the main method to get query for SQLite3(swift), go through all results(if multiple), append them and return the whole data at the end.

```
//You say you want to return array of rows
func getById(id:Int64) -> [Row]? {
    //Create empty array
    var data = [Row]()
    //build the query. I use UsersTable.entityName.filter(), but I don't know your structure
    let query=Users.filter(Id==id)
    do {
        //for cycle to go to all of the results
        for rowInfo in try db!.pluck(query) {
            //Create variable. I don't know what you want. You can create it as Row() and after that add the information
            let userData = Row()
            //you need to use rowInfo, it store the SQL data. inside the key is from the table Structure. You used Users.filter, so I guess the struct with all column names is Users, so Users.name is the 'name' column
            userData.name = rowInfo[Users.name]
            //Apend the data
            data.append(userData)
        }
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
    //Return the array of Rows
    return data
}
```